# Flutter Json error path = '/data/user/0/com.example.projeto1/app_flutter/data.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to open my file to be able to save to it but this error is occurring
I didn't add any permissions on AndroidManifest.xml

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.readData().then((value) => (data){
        controller.list = json.decode(data);
    });
  }

Future<File> _getFile() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return File("${directory.path}/data.json");
  }

  Future<File> _saveData() async {
    String data = json.encode(list);

    final file = await _getFile();
    return file.writeAsString(data);
  }

  Future<String> readData() async {
    try {
      final file = await _getFile();

      return file.readAsString();
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the error says, you are trying to save to a file that dosent exists, so you need to create the file if it dosent. change your `_getFile` method from

```
Future<File> _getFile() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return File("${directory.path}/data.json");
}
```

to

```
Future<File> _getFile() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File("${directory.path}/data.json");

    final doesExist = await file.exists();

    if(!doseExist)
       file = await file.create(); 

    return file;
}
```

now you are checking if the file exists at the location `{directory.path}/data.json`, if it dosent exist then we create it using the `File.create()` method which returns a `Future<File>` then return the newly created file.